# How to instantiate class from name string in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, string, class, instantiation

**How we can instantiate class from it's name string in Ruby-on-Rails?**

For example we have it's name in database in format like "ClassName" or "my_super_class_name".

How we can create object from it?

**Solution:**

Was looking for it myself, but not found, so here it is.
[Ruby-on-Rails API Method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize)

```
name = "ClassName"
instance = name.constantize.new
```

It can be even not formatted, we can user string method *.classify*

```
name = "my_super_class"
instance = name.classify.constantize.new
```

Of course maybe this is not very 'Rails way', but it solves it's purpose.

Comment: Just FYI, constantize is an ActiveSupport convenience method that does `Object.const_get` and Classify is an ActiveSupport method that tries to turn a string into a standard class formatting.

What you are doing is identical to Evginey's answer, with some additional checks. While constantize is probably a better solution(because it does sanity checks), it helps to understand the tools you using.

Comment: Thank you for this, to be honest didn't checked what it do in manual.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
klass = Object.const_get "ClassName"
```

about class methods

```
class KlassExample
    def self.klass_method
        puts "Hello World from Class method"
    end
end
klass = Object.const_get "KlassExample"
klass.klass_method

irb(main):061:0> klass.klass_method
Hello World from Class method
```

Comment: With that you cannot access class methods. My solution above works correctly with class methods.

Comment: `Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
irb(main):001:0> name = "PartnerGateway"
=> "PartnerGateway"
irb(main):002:0> klass = name.constantize.new
=> #<PartnerGateway id: nil, name: nil, partner_id: nil, gateway: nil, changed_by_id: nil, deleted_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):003:0> klass.name
=> nil`

Comment: `irb(main):005:0> klass2 = Object.const_get name
=> PartnerGateway(id: integer, name: string, partner_id: integer, gateway: string, changed_by_id: integer, deleted_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
irb(main):006:0> klass2.name
=> "PartnerGateway"
irb(main):008:0> klass2.id
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<Class:0xac3e4c0>`

Comment: With my method you can do the both ways.

"KlassExample".constantize.self_method_name

and

klass = "KlassExample".constantize.new
klass.normal_method

Comment: yeah... it don't prove anything you obviously don't call new them you use "Object.const_get"  
try klass2.new.name

Comment: Well, so that can be done by klass2 = (Object.const_get name).new like you do with klass = name.constantize.new

Comment: that your problem? why do you so insist on proving your way somehow better when it obviously do the exact same thing?

Comment: You think that your solution is elegant and correct? Check top comment please.

Answer (score 51):

Others may also be looking for an alternative that does not throw an error if it fails to find the class. `safe_constantize` is just that.

```rb
class MyClass
end

"my_class".classify.safe_constantize.new #  #<MyClass:0x007fec3a96b8a0>
"omg_evil".classify.safe_constantize.new #  nil
```

Answer (score 19):

You can simply convert a string and initialize a class out of it by:

```
klass_name = "Module::ClassName"
klass_name.constantize
```

To initialize a new object:

```
klass_name.constantize.new
```

I hope this turns out to be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't use this!
 It's very vulnerable approach: https://www.praetorian.com/blog/ruby-unsafe-reflection-vulnerabilities

Comment: @TiSer Can you please explain how is it vulnerable as long as I don't constantize a string from my request parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the blog. This is quite helpful. As long as we use constantize without passing any request params to it and enclose it in a private function, I don't see a threat.

Comment: This line in the blog shared by you is extremely critical to keep in mind when working with reflections: Reflection is used to modifying the nature of a program at runtime and should not be used with Strings from untrusted sources.

Comment: In your direct example - yes, but I don't know where you will want to make such object transformation from single whole string to a class in real world.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised nobody is considering security and hacking in their responses.  Instantiation of an arbitrary string that likely came even indirectly from user input is asking for trouble and hacking.  We all should/must be whitelisting unless we're sure the string is fully controlled and monitored

```
def class_for(name)
  {
    "foo" => Foo,
    "bar" => Bar,
  }[name] || raise UnknownClass
end

class_for(name_wherever_this_came_from).create!(params_somehow)
```

How you would know the appropriate params arbitrarily without having a whitelist would be challenging but you get the idea.